# How to check if a "." has been input into a TextBox?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to check if a "." has been input into a TextBox?

is it something like:

```
if (TextBox1.Text == ".")
{
    //Do something...
}
```

because when I do this, it seems to not check what is in the TextBox1 and just continue with the next line of code

Here is my code:

```
private void btnContinue1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HouseholdNoTextBox.Text))
        {
            textBlockError2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            textBlockError1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;                
        }
        if (HouseholdNoTextBox.Text.Length >= 3)
        {//checking to see if it has a length greater than 2
            textBlockError1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; // collapse the first error box if it is visible
            textBlockError2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // and make visible the second
        }
        if (HouseholdNoTextBox.Text == ".")
        {
            textBlockError1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;  
        }
        if (HouseholdNoTextBox.Text.Length <= 2 && HouseholdNoTextBox.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            textBlockError1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            textBlockError2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

I have also tried:

```
if (HouseholdNoTextBox.Text.Contains("."))
        {
            textBlockError1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;  
        }
```

I have also tried:

```
private void btnContinue1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string houseHoldNo = HouseholdNoTextBox.Text.ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HouseholdNoTextBox.Text) || houseHoldNo.Contains(".")) // adding it here along with the first if statement
        {
            textBlockError2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            textBlockError1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;                
        }
    }
```

I have also tried:

private void btnContinue1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string houseHoldNo = HouseholdNoTextBox.Text.ToString();

```
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HouseholdNoTextBox.Text))
        {
            textBlockError2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            textBlockError1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;                
        }
        if (houseHoldNo.Contains("."))
        {
            textBlockError1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```

and this above code does the same as the other.. it skips to the last if statement.

Comment: Well where are you putting that code? It has to be in some event which is fired when the textbox text changes...

Comment: Rather then having a button always enabled, handle TextChanged or KeyUp events on the TextBox and enable the button only when your conditions are satisfied.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on the line where you're evaluating `houseHoldNo.Text` to see what its value is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by checking for the "."

`if(TextBox1.Text.Contains("."))`
`{`
`//Do Something`
`}`

And then handle the event `TextBox.TextChanged` and place the above code in it.

Comment: Yes i saw that but my main point was to use this inside the TexBox.TextChanged event

Answer (score 1):

I would try to type `this.Focus` as your first action under button event (this will hide keyboard). Then in next line create variable like `string tbContent = HouseholdNoTextBox.Text` and finally in all 'if' statements use this variable instead of `HouseholdNoTextBox.Text`. In first attempt set breakpoint on first 'if' and check if your string has value ('.' or smth else). If yes, both compare methods (==, Contains()) should work imo.

Comment: I haven't noticed that in your third attempt you created string based on textbox.text Anyway try this.Focus as it will update all controls values on page.